# error: metadata-generation-failed python pip

Tags: python, pip

when I try to install uwsgi it gives me the following error. and I can’t understand why, could you give me a help?

```
Collecting uwsgi
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.21.tar.gz (808 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\MICAD13-TS-ALE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s8777u24\uwsgi_cea0c3a9082b4906a62240cca86dffc2\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          import uwsgiconfig as uc
        File "C:\Users\MICAD13-TS-ALE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s8777u24\uwsgi_cea0c3a9082b4906a62240cca86dffc2\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
          uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
      AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to update setuptools to the latest version 68.0.0, but I can’t fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buwsgi%5D+uname